# How to select quantity of individual cartItems in KnockoutJS

Tags: javascript, jquery, knockout.js

Hello im fairly new to knock out and im trying to have my array cartItems auto select their quantity from a drop down. Here is my code:

**VIEW**

```
<div data-bind="foreach: cartItems">
   <h3 data-bind="text: fullname"></h3>
   <p data-bind="text: sku"></p>
   <select data-bind="quantityDropdown: number"></select>
</div>
```

**VIEWMODEL**

```
var number = 50;
ko.bindingHandlers.quantityDropdown = {
    update: function (element) {
        for (var i = 1; i < number + 1; i++) {
            var selectedQty = "";

            for (var x = 0; x < self.cartItems().length; x++) {
                var itemqty = parseFloat(self.cartItems()[x].qty, 10);

                if (i === itemqty) {
                    selectedQty = " selected='selected'";
                }
            }
            // Add each option element to the select here
            $(element).append("<option value='" + i + "' " + selectedQty + " class='quantity'>" + i + "</option>");
        }
    }
};
```

Now i put two items in the cart and the drop down appears. But the "selected" number is the same for both items in the cart? I know its because its not item specific. but I'm not sure how to make it item specific in Knockoutjs.

Comment: Why don't you use the `options` binding handler? Also, you don't make any use of the `number` parameter you're passing to your `quantityDrowndown` handler...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Working example:
http://jsfiddle.net/GSvnh/5085/



**view :**

```
 <div data-bind="foreach: CartItems">
     <h3 data-bind="text: FullName"></h3>
      <p data-bind="text: Sku"></p>
      <select name="qty" class="form-control" data-bind="foreach: QuantityDropdown ,value:SelectedQuantity">
    <option data-bind="value: Value,text:Name"></option>
  </select>
</div>
```

**VM:**

```
  $(function () {
    var MainViewModel = function () {
    var self = this;
    self.CartItems = ko.observableArray([]);
    //For example you get below array of objects as response
    var response = [{ fullname: "ABC", sku: "1234567789", qty: 12 },
                    { fullname: "AAA", sku: "2323227789", qty: 20 },
                    { fullname: "BBB", sku: "2311227789", qty: 33 }
    ];

    //you map your response and for each item you create a new CartItemViewModel   
    self.CartItems($.map(response, function (item) {
      return new CartItemViewModel(item);
    }));

    }

    var CartItemViewModel = function (data) {
     var self = this;
     var number = 50;
     self.FullName = ko.observable(data.fullname);
     self.Sku = ko.observable(data.sku);
     self.QuantityDropdown = ko.observableArray();

     for (var i = 1; i < number + 1; i++) {
       self.QuantityDropdown.push({ Value: i, Name: i });
     }
     self.SelectedQuantity = ko.observable(parseFloat(data.qty, 10));
     self.SelectedQuantity.subscribe(function (newValue) {
        alert("selected Qty : "+  newValue);
     })
   }
   ko.applyBindings(new MainViewModel());

  })
```

Comment: Hey there. yeah it keeps giving me that data is undefined? self.SelectedQuantity = ko.observable(parseFloat(data.qty, 10)); any ideas where i can populate the rows qty there?

Comment: my cart items are in this format:     self.cartItems = ko.observableArray(arrayFromJson);

Comment: yeah my im getting my array from a cookie using:
var cookiestring = $.cookie("cookieCart");
var arrayFromJson = JSON.parse(cookiestring);
then the array prints out as [Object
fullname: "Item1"
qty: 3
sku: "ACS1"

Object
fullname: "Item2"
qty: 1
sku: "ACS2"]

Comment: from which i call it in my viewmodel: function AppViewModel() {
    var self = this;
    self.cartItems = ko.observableArray(arrayFromJson);.....

Comment: i tried putting     self.selectedQuantity = ko.observable(parseFloat(self.cartItems.qty, 10)); since self.cartItems.qty should be the same as your data.qty...? but i get errors so im not sure

Comment: replace your JSON with the jsffile link that I sent and open up the console to see what data you are getting (http://jsfiddle.net/GSvnh/5087/)

Comment: I figured it out. i was missing the MainViewModel. Your way was more efficient for iterating through the array.